# OpenCV MatchShapes for two very similar contour return BIG difference = 244

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two similar images [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjAoQ.jpg) and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrsoL.jpg).
As you can see - the images absolutely match!

here is my c++ code:

```
vector<vector<cv::Point>> LoadImage1(cv::Mat m)
{
    cv::Mat g_gray, g_blur, g_binary;
    

    cv::cvtColor(m, g_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 1);
    cv::blur(g_gray, g_blur, cv::Size2i(3, 3));
    cv::threshold(g_blur, g_binary, 80, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    //cv::OutputArrayOfArrays cnt1;
    vector< vector< cv::Point> > cnt;
    cv::findContours(g_binary, cnt, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    return cnt;
}
int main()
{
    cv::Mat m1 = cv::imread("C:\\..Here First image..jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    cv::Mat m2 = cv::imread("C:\\..Here Second image..jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    vector<vector<cv::Point>> cnt1 = LoadImage1(m1);
    vector<vector<cv::Point>> cnt2 = LoadImage1(m2);
    
    cv::drawContours(m1, cnt1, -1, cv::Scalar::all(255));
    cv::drawContours(m2, cnt2, -1, cv::Scalar::all(255));

    
    double res = cv::matchShapes(cnt1[0], cnt2[0], cv::CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0);
    printf("res=%f", res);
    
    while (true) {
        if (cv::waitKey(100 /* milliseconds */) == 27) break;
    }
}
```

Here is my contours:
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGsNa.jpg) and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJnyr.jpg)

And this is the result:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsgwO.jpg)

Why some big 244!!! The images is totally the same and the contours very similar. Why?
Please somebody help. Maybe i am made a mistake in code?

Comment: How do you judge the value is too big? In other words, how did you estimate the expected value?

Comment: I expect the result should be <1. Or How can i deside that two shapes is matched?

Comment: [undeclared crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/contours-matching-by-matchshapes-whitch-return-big-difference-for-two-similar-shapes/12292